# Java determines which method to call using a generic type argument?

Tags: java, generics

To my knowledge, Java drops the generic type argument information during runtime. It is only used on compilation to perform checks, for example, is this particular method call valid or not.

Today I came across the following piece of code, in which, seemingly, Java determines by the collection/list type argument, which constructor to call:

```
public static class MyClass {
    public MyClass(final Collection<String> coll) {
        System.out.println("Constructor 1");
    }
    public MyClass(final List<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println("Constructor 2");
    }
}
```

The following calls are made:

```
new MyClass(new HashSet<String>()); // Constructor 1
new MyClass(new ArrayList<String>()); // Constructor 1
new MyClass(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Constructor 2
```

Now, if I erase the type arguments:

```
public static class MyClass2 {
    public MyClass2(final Collection coll) {
        System.out.println("Constructor 1");
    }
    public MyClass2(final List list) {
        System.out.println("Constructor 2");
    }
}
```

...The same calls act as I would expect them to; constructor invocation which uses a list argument goes for the constructor which meets its needs "most precisely":

```
new MyClass2(new HashSet<String>()); // Constructor 1
new MyClass2(new ArrayList<String>()); // Constructor 2
new MyClass2(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Constructor 2
```

It appears that generics information is being stored in the compiled class (in this case, MyClass) and is not being discarded after all, but it should be discarded. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: +1 good question. I have a vague idea of why it might be, but I am thrilled to see a good answer to that.

Comment: I guess it might have something to do with Java picking the method to use at compile-time?

Comment: At compile time the compiler selects the "closest match" from a set of overloaded methods.  The generic parms are affecting the algorithm the compiler uses to make the selection.

Comment: I separated MyClass and MyClass2 into a separate class, compiled it. Then put the _main_ method into a separate class, compiled it and called it. The result was the same. I suppose there _is_ some kind of generic type argument information stored.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What happens here is that the compiler can distinguish the two constructors by using generics, so it does *before* creating the byte code and *before* stripping generics.

In the middle case, it will tell the VM to invoke `MyClass2<init>(Collection)` (i.e. generate byte code which matches this specific constructor).

The VM doesn't try to determine which method matches at runtime. That would be way too slow. Instead, it relies on the compiler creating very specific instructions.

This is why the code above works even though the generic information has been erased at runtime.

**[EDIT]** To clarify: The byte code contains additional information which the compiler can see and use. You can get the same information via reflection.

Erasure means that the byte code interpreter and JIT doesn't care about generics which is why you can't have `setFoo(List<String>)` and `setFoo(List<Integer>)` in the same class: While the compiler could distinguish the two, the runtime can't.

Specifically, when you examine a method via reflection, you will get generics information but the byte code interpreter / JIT doesn't use reflection. Instead, it uses the compressed method signature which reads something like `Method com/pany/Type/setFoo(Ljava.util.List;)V` - no generics here anymore.

Related:

- [How the Java virtual machine handles method invocation and return](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1997/jw-06-hood.html)
- [Why do the Java bytecodes for invoking methods implicitly acquire and release monitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130203/why-do-the-java-bytecodes-for-invoking-methods-implicitly-acquire-and-release-mo)
- [invokevirtual docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.invokevirtual)

Comment: I separated the code with the classes and the main method into two separate classes. Compiled the class with classes, the compiled the class with the main method. Called the class with the main method. But the result was the same. It means that the generic type information is being stored in the first class, which is then used when compiling the second class?

Comment: Compiled `.class` files keep all of their generics information.  Generic information about your class definitions stays with the program forever; generic type information is only lost on _objects_ of those generic types; e.g. a `List<String>` will only know it is a `List`.

Comment: @SergejsPogorelovs: The compiler and the runtime use different information sources. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks. My code was specifying, what generics it was using, and it was also specified in the compiled code, what generics the constructors had. So the code understood which constructor it should call.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't notice that you are dealing with constructor. Anyways, the below arguments is valid even for constructor.

---

Method invocation for the overloaded method is resolved at compile time by the compiler. And generics are used for type check at compile time only. So, this has nothing to do with the type erasure, which is completely a runtime business.

### Consider your first case:

```
public MyClass(final Collection<String> coll)
public MyClass(final List<Integer> list)
```

Now, when you invoke the method as:

```
new MyClass(new HashSet<String>()); // Constructor 1
new MyClass(new ArrayList<String>()); // Constructor 1
new MyClass(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Constructor 2
```

Compiler will decide which method has the more specific type for the passed argument. Consider case 2, where is your main doubt I guess.

`ArrayList<String>` is a subtype of `Collection<String>`, but it's not a subtype of `List<Integer>`. Generics are invariant. So, compiler will bind the 2nd method invocation to the first method.

### Now, consider your 2nd case, where you are using raw types:

```
public MyClass2(final Collection coll)
public MyClass2(final List list)
```

Now, `ArrayList<String>` is a subtype of `List` and `Collection` both. But `List` is more specific to `ArrayList` than `Collection`. So, compiler will bind the method call:

```
new MyClass2(new ArrayList<String>());
```

with the one taking `List` as argument.

---

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html)

  - [Why doesn't method overloading work as I expect it?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ050)
  - [Why doesn't method overriding work as I expect it?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ051)

Comment: I think that what was bugging me was the thought that if generic information is being discarded during runtime, why store it at all when compiling the code, so it's probably discarded right when the class has compiled. But I was wrong because it is still needed for compiling other classes in the future, which would depend on our class with generics. So I presume that generic information is always stored in the bytecode but at the runtime it's still discarded? Are there no cases when some code would like to call a method with generics in arguments, for which the detailed info was not loaded?

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, the compiler chooses the *narrowest* type that matches.

In the raw parameter version, it's obvious what will be chosen, but in the generic version, the type of the collection/list is included in the matching information: An ArrayList is both a Collection and a List, but you can see it's easy to break the tie by also comparing the ArrayList's type - now only one method will still match.